# navigation between deep nested graphs using Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

structure of navigations graph that is implemented is like image below.

[image: arrows represent include tags]

but unfortunatly when navigating from top fragments (OneFragment, TwoFragment and ThreeFragment) to lower fragments (OtherFragment),
an exception occurs:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination [package_name]:id/otherFragment referenced from action [package_name]:id/action_OneFragment_to_OtherFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination([package_name]:id/oneFragment)`

the reason for this structure is to avoid large Navigation.xml files and also [NaviagtionAdvancedSample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) old version is used in project, where each BottomNavigaationView tabs should have their own graph.